# How to wait for multiple request to complete in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angular-promise

I want multiple methods to get loaded completely before I proceed in my web application. For that I have done following -

```
      function getData(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get("/echo/json/").success(function(data, status) {
            getData2();
            getData3();
            $timeout(function(){        
                 defer.resolve(data);
            }, 1000); 
        });
        return defer.promise;
      }
```

here, getData2() and getData3() will also do ajax calls. So I have to wait these methods to complete there call and then I have to return promise of main method.

This is working good , but giving me performance issue. 
Any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If order is not important use $q.all() as follow:

```
$q.all([getData1(), getData2(), getData3()])
    .then(function(result){
        // result[0] is output of getData1() 
        // result[1] is output of getData2()
        // result[2] is output of getData3()
    });
```

But if order is important, call them in chain as follow:

```
getData1()
    .then(function(result1){
         return getData2();
    })
    .then(function(result2){
         return getData3();
    })        
   .then(function(result3){
         // your other codes
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all `getDataX` functions return promises, you should chain them like so:

```
getData()
.then(function(result){
  return getData1();
})
.then(function(result1){
  return getData2();
})...
```